# Setting v-bind:class with method not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to set the style of a div with

```
    <div v-for="q in questions" v-bind:class="{seen:isseen(q),unseen:isunseen(q)}">
```

The problem is that these functions get computed for each q, but I *also* need them to get recomputed when a different variable updates.

```
     methods:{
       isseen: function(id_1){
         if(ans[id_1]==2)
           return true;
         else
           return false
       },
       isunseen:function(id_1){
         if(ans[id_1]!=2)
           return true;
         else
           return false;
       }
     }
```

Here, I need the

```
    v-bind:class="{seen:isseen(q),unseen:isunseen(q)}"
```

computed even when `ans[id_1]` changes.

I have looked at the `computed` and `watch` approach, but cannot figure out what will work here.

Comment: Replace `methods` with `computed`, methods are not reactive (and not even expecting returned value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to work with this.

In place of
`v-bind:class="{seen:isseen(q),unseen:isunseen(q)}"` and subsequently checking `ans[id_1]!=2` and `ans[id_1]==2`, I instead did
`v-bind:class="{seen:ans[q]==2,unseen:ans[q]!=2}`.

However, Vue [cannot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)  detect changes that look like `ans[indexOfItem] = newValue`[This means the v-bind:class will **not be triggered by changes** in `ans`], so values must instead be set by `Vue.set(ans, indexOfItem, newValue)` for their effects to be reflected in reactive classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtered `questions` like this:

```
<div v-for="q in filteredQuestions" :class="{seen:q.isseen,unseen:q.isunseen}">

computed: {
    filteredQuestions(){
        for(var i=0, ii=this.questions.length; i<ii; i++) {
            //this.questions[i].isseen = ...
            //this.questions[i].isunseen = ...
        }
    }
},
```

or computed function:

```
<div v-for="q in questions" v-bind:class="{seen:isseen(q),unseen:isunseen(q)}">

methods:{
    isseen: () => (id_1) => {
        //...
    },
    isunseen: () => (id_1) => {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: also `:class="{seen:q.isseen,unseen:!q.isseen}"` =`:class="{seen:q.isseen,unseen:q.isunseen}"`.